# RecyclerView Scrolling Slow

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

When i get the data from Json And put in the recyclerview. It is scrolling very slowly? Plz Help me to solve this solution.

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
            adapter1 = new Landing_recycler_adapter(MainActivity.this, movieList);
            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
            gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL); // set Horizontal Orientation
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set LayoutManager to RecyclerView
    //        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));


            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);

            getJsonData();
```

Comment: why are you setting layoutmanager twice?

Comment: @sanjeev one line is under comment LOL :)

Comment: Glad you edited the post. Are you using a scrollview outside recyclerview?

Comment: 2. You get `getJsonData();` after setting adapter? 
3. What does movieList contain? 
P.S Please provide more code..

Comment: I didnot get exact answer.

Comment: I am just asking. why recyclerview is move slowly when we get online data?

Comment: Please add adapter, viewholder and getJsonData code.

Comment: I have added recycler adapter. and view holder.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
            getJsonData();
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
            adapter1 = new Landing_recycler_adapter(MainActivity.this, movieList);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

or

```
            getJsonData();
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
            adapter1 = new Landing_recycler_adapter(MainActivity.this, movieList);

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: No Logcate Error. Just recyclerview moving slowly. means performance is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

And also disable nested scrolling of RecyclerView

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Please provide more code, this issue may be related to other actions.

Comment: No Logcate Error. Just recyclerview moving slowly. means performance is very bad.

Comment: If you are setting image to the imageView in item view of recyclerView, then just use Glide or Picasso for to do it.